# The widgetset in use does not seem to be built for the Vaadin version in use

Tags: maven, vaadin

I'd like to add Vaadin chart into my project, I've add maven dependency, install licence and vaadin clean, update widgetset and compile. But when I run the application and open localhost:8080, got error in console:

```
The widgetset in use does not seem to be built for the Vaadin
version in use. This might cause strange problems - a
recompile/deploy is strongly recommended.
Vaadin version: 8.0.0
Widgetset version: 8.0-SNAPSHOT
```

and following message on UI: https://www.screencast.com/t/deDF6kVsvDdU

Here are vaadin dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                <style>OBF</style>
                <strict>true</strict>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I fix this?

UPDATE:
Here are the output of `mvn vaadin:clean vaadin:compile` (running this do not solve my issue):

```
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.0.4:clean (default-cli) @ test ---
[WARNING] GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.0.4:compile (default-cli) @ test ---
[WARNING] GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found.
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.0.0
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.0.0
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

I've also try to add annotation `@Widgetset("AppWidgetset")` to VaadinUI class and recompile, this time I got error on UI:

```
Failed to load the widgetset: ./VAADIN/widgetsets/AppWidgetset/AppWidgetset.nocache.js?
```

So, I've add WidgetSet.gwt.xml near VaadinUi class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.addon.charts.Widgetset" />
</module>
```

Recompile all, but still get

```
 Failed to load the widgetset: ./VAADIN/widgetsets/AppWidgetset/AppWidgetset.nocache.js?
```

Comment: Try cleaning before recompiling the widgetset and check the log to ensure that the widgetset is indeed recompiled, something along the lines of `mvn  vaadin:clean vaadin:compile`

Comment: I've updated question, recompile does not help

Comment: **1)** Take care when updating the plugin and dependency versions, you have `vaadin-maven-plugin:8.0.4` and `com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.0.0`. **2)** How are you packaging/running the application?

Comment: I run it from Intellij Idea (it is Spring Boot application)

Comment: 1) Recompile with single version 8.0.0 for all packages does not help

Comment: You should see a line reading `auto discovered modules [whatever.package..WidgetSet]` but from your log `GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found` indicates that no widget set was found, hence none was compiled. Where in your sources/packages did you put your `WidgetSet.gwt.xml`?

Comment: Actually I haven't such file, and looks like haven't clear understanding why should use it to build Chart. Is there any samples of what should be in WidgetSet.gwt.xml?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here are some useful links: [client side compiling docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientside/clientside-compiling.html), [client side module descriptor](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientside/clientside-module.html#clientside.module), [widgetset webinar with changes from v7.7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EXhNvfyCtE&list=PLcRrh9hGNalnmA1mbDS0NBuq6N3Mnw2u1), and finally [actual file sample from their chart demo](https://github.com/vaadin/charts-tutorial/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml)

Answer (score 5):

Add vaadin client dep

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

My POM as below and it worked. Build command as normal: **mvn package**. Only need to compile widget once so remove plugin when you build your app to reduce compile time.
VAADIN folder to compile is at: \src\main\webapp\VAADIN

```
<!-- Only support to compile Vaadin widgetsets -->
   .......
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>8.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
       .....
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```